# How can I get su screen PID on Debian8?

Tags: linux, debian, gnu-screen, su, pid

I want to run this command by another user (so with su): `screen -ALmdS server_mta ./mta-server -n`

It's okay: `su - server_2 -c 'screen -ALmdS server_mta ./mta-server -n`

But I need the PID of screen, but when i try to get, I got anoter PIDs.

I tried this method:

```
su - server_2 -c "screen -ALmdS server_mta ./mta-server -n >>~/outlog 2>&1 & echo \$! "
```

But it was give 5996 PID, but when I check it with `ps ax |grep server_mta` the result was:

```
5997 ?        Ss     0:00 SCREEN -ALmdS server_mta ./mta-server -n
6023 pts/45   S+     0:00 grep server_mta
```

I tried this command:

```
su - server_2 -c 'screen -ALmdS server_mta ./mta-server -n > /dev/null & ps ax |grep  $! '
```

And the result was:

```
6829 ?        R      0:00 screen -ALmdS server_mta ./mta-server -n
6831 ?        S      0:00 grep 6829
```

I thought I got the PID, and when I checked again with `ps ax |grep server_mta`, I got an another PID. And the difference here is the screen is lowercase, and when I check in `ps ax |grep server_mta`, this is uppercase.

How can I got the PID of my screen process which is ran by another user with su?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
su - server_2 -c "screen -ALmdS server_mta ./mta-server -n  >>/home/out 2>&1"; pgrep -u server_2 |  xargs ps -p | grep SCREEN | cut -f1 -d' ' | head -n 1
```

This return the PID of screen.